# Why does Windows report "Wifi 7"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-driver

A while back, I was having some driver problems with a USB WiFi adapter. I had to reinstall it a few times. I figured out why it wasn't working (Virtualbox for some reason) and it works now. However, whenever I go into the settings (by clicking on the WiFi icon in the tray), it says "WiFi 7." I think it is because my computer thinks there were 7 different WiFi adapters ever plugged in. How can I reset this to say "WiFi 1" or maybe even just "WiFi"?

[image: Network Connections showing "WiFi 7"]

Comment: Because Windows has in the past saved 6 other wireless connections.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I know that. I'm asking how to reset that number to 0.

Comment: I was only answering the question contained within the title of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't find this sooner: :-)

**Steps:**

1. Search for this by going to the start screen and typing your search:

   > Network connections

   [image]
2. Right click the adapter and hit "rename."
   [image]

Like I said, it's so simple, yet I didn't realize I could rename adapters. I found this after researching other adapter problems and thought I'd post this to help others out. I thought the name was defined somewhere in the driver or deep in the Windows kernel.